# MLT filter to control audio volume

Tags: mlt

I want to attach audio to video in such a way that the music plays in background in a very low volume. What would be the ideal way to do it? I cannot get the volume filter working in this case.

This is what I am trying

melt 1.mp4 -filter volume gain=20db -audio-track bensound-buddy.mp3 -attach volume gain=-10db

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to decrease the volume from one track too and I found why it didn't work. Try to use that instead :
melt 1.mp4 -attach volume level=20db -track bensound-buddy.mp3 -attach volume level=-10db